# Datatables fnDraw doesn't work

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am using datatables which gets it's data from a json file.

```
var date=new Date();
var day=date.getDate();
var dataTable = $('#.main_content table').dataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bSort": false,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "bjQueryUI": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": 'sources/data.json',
                    "fnServerData": fnServerObjectToArray()
                });
```

As you can see I'm using a function to extract the data from the json file.

```
fnServerObjectToArray = function () {
            return function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "GET",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "success": function (json) {
                        var a = [];
                        var data = json.aoData;
                        for (var i = 0, iLen = data.appointments.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                            var inner = [];
                            inner.push(data.appointments[i].time);
                            if (data.appointments[i].CHT111[day]) {
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].CHT111[day]);
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].DOB[day]);
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].Patient[day]);
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].Visit_Reason[day]);
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].Room[day]);
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].Scheduled[day]);
                            }
                            else {
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].CHT111.default);
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].DOB.default);
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].Patient.default);
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].Visit_Reason.default);
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].Room.default);
                                inner.push(data.appointments[i].Scheduled.default);
                            }
                            a.push(inner);
                        }
                        json.aaData = a;
                        fnCallback(json);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

The problem is that I have a button which changes the day variable and after that calls the fnDraw() method which doesn't work.

Comment: how are you calling the fnDraw?  Do you have a code snippet?

Comment: $("button").click(function(){ dataTable.fnDraw();})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the the datatables documentation fnDraw does not reload Ajax data.  However, there is a plugin that was written called fnReloadAjax that will do exactly what you are looking for.  The following code is the plugin code, just save it as a js file and load it after you load the datatables js, but before you initialize your table:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function ( oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw )
{
if ( typeof sNewSource != 'undefined' && sNewSource != null )
{
    oSettings.sAjaxSource = sNewSource;
}
this.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, true );
var that = this;
var iStart = oSettings._iDisplayStart;
var aData = [];

this.oApi._fnServerParams( oSettings, aData );

oSettings.fnServerData( oSettings.sAjaxSource, aData, function(json) {
    /* Clear the old information from the table */
    that.oApi._fnClearTable( oSettings );

    /* Got the data - add it to the table */
    var aData =  (oSettings.sAjaxDataProp !== "") ?
        that.oApi._fnGetObjectDataFn( oSettings.sAjaxDataProp )( json ) : json;

    for ( var i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ )
    {
        that.oApi._fnAddData( oSettings, aData[i] );
    }

    oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
    that.fnDraw();

    if ( typeof bStandingRedraw != 'undefined' && bStandingRedraw === true )
    {
        oSettings._iDisplayStart = iStart;
        that.fnDraw( false );
    }

    that.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, false );

    /* Callback user function - for event handlers etc */
    if ( typeof fnCallback == 'function' && fnCallback != null )
    {
        fnCallback( oSettings );
    }
}, oSettings );
};
```

Now you can just call the following code whenever you want to reload the table with new filtered data:

```
dataTable.fnReloadAjax( 'sources/data.json' );
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. The datable isn't redrawed and also this function requests the file twice

Comment: Ok! I found out what wasn't working. The ReloadAjax() function doesn't work with ServerSide Processing on.